# calrification on Update command on a table

Tags: sql, oracle

When I update the emailcontent column for the below table, email content column got duplicated and this is the command that i used to update, Not sure  whether the update command caused the duplicate. Below are the steps that i have done in the order.

```
CREATE TABLE notifications
(
  notifymessagetype  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  emailcontent      NCLOB,
  order      NUMBER,
)

INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','*****PLEASE DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL ******','1')
INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','OrderName','2')
INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','OrderCode','3')
INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','OrderDate','4')
INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','OrderType','5')
INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype,emailcontent, order) values ('emailbody','OrderNumber','6')
```

then I altered the table and added a column and inserted a value in it

```
ALTER TABLE  notifications
RENAME COLUMN emailcontent TO emailcontent_OLD;

ALTER TABLE  notifications
ADD COLUMN emailcontent NCLOB;

UPDATE notifications SET emailcontent  = emailcontent_OLD; 

INSERT into notifications (notifymessagetype, emailcontent_OLD,order,emailcontent) values ('emailbody','The Order has been emailed','7','The Order has been emailed')
```

table before the update command: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7PP6.png)

table after the update command: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlaVa.png)

Comment: mysql or oracle? And all looks as your code should do.

Comment: You've intentionally duplicated the column and its contents; though you seem to have your images the wrong way around. (But please don't use images - put the query results in the question as formatted text). So what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: The schema is in oracle

Comment: There is no question here. You made a table. Put some data in it. Renamed a column. Added a column with the original name of the one you renamed. Updated the new column to have the same values as the old column. Then you added another record to the table.

Comment: @Alex i ran an update command and the email content columns got duplicated. I am not sure it's because of my update command. Wanted to know whether my update query turns first image into second one or not?

Comment: @cptmisery my question is-- is that row with order number 4 got duplicated because of the update query or not?

Comment: Update statement updates the record on the columns you have chosen. If you want the old email content with blank, then update again with null or in the same statement as a second column like this -> UPDATE notifications SET emailcontent  = emailcontent_OLD, emailcontent_old = null;

Comment: No, what you noticed is not caused by your operations (of renaming a column, adding a new one, copying data from a column to the other, and adding a row). Somebody or something crated that duplicate ROW. Did you notice that in the new table, not only is row 4 duplicated, but also row 6 is MISSING? It may be the result of an UPDATE done by someone else or something else.

Comment: @saireddy, Oh, I missed that record. However, nothing in the code you have here would have duplicated that line.

Comment: Something also removed the row with ID 6. Or maybe more likely updated the row with ID 6 to have the same values as the old row with ID 4. The statements you showed did not do that, either way. Also your images both have the row with ID 7, which doesn't match the order you said you did things. We can't help if you don't include everything you actually did, in the order you did it.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the clarification,  i have run this query for the notifications table in QA environment and the field got duplicated and row 6 was missing. I was not sure whether the update query that i have written is causing this issue or not. Clarified

Comment: @alex, i have included what all I did

Comment: Then as mathguy said, someone else must have changed the data. Or you're looking at different databses, or schemas. What you've shown can't change the data the way you've shown. And you haven't explained how/why both images show row 7.